# ¿Cómo llamar este método?

Tags: java, java-swing

La finalidad del programa es hacer una especie de traductor en el cual tu guardas las palabras y traducciones, para después buscarlas y que te entregue la traducción deseada,el Español es el idioma de entrada(Inglés y Francés, son las traducciones), mi duda es cómo llamar el metodo: "busquedapalabra" desde la interfaz... agradecería si encuentran algún error en mis metodos!! 
Aquí es donde tengo el método:

```
public class Traductor {

    public Traduccion arregloFra [] = new Traduccion [10];
    public Traduccion arregloIng [] = new Traduccion [10];



    public Traductor(){

    }

    public void agregar(Traduccion t1, int i, int index){

        if (i==1){
            arregloIng [index] = t1;
        }
        if (i ==0){
            arregloFra [index] = t1;
        }
    }
    public String busquedapalabra(String palabra, int dick){
        String traduccion = "null";
        if (dick ==1){

            for (int i = 0; i<arregloIng.length; i++)
                if(palabra.equalsIgnoreCase(arregloIng[i].getEspañol())){
                    traduccion = arregloIng[i].getIngles();
                    break;
                }
        }


    else{

        for(int i =0; i<arregloFra.length; i++){
            if (palabra.equalsIgnoreCase(arregloFra[i].getEspañol())){
                traduccion = arregloFra[i].getFrances();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return traduccion;
}
}
```

Aquí es donde lo quiero llamar:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TraductorApp {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textPalabra;
    private JTextField textTraduccion;
    private JTextField NumPalIng;
    private JTextField NumPalFran;
    private JTextField AgregarEsp;
    private JTextField AgregarIng;
    private JTextField AgregarFran;
    Traductor arr1 = new Traductor();
    Traduccion trad1 = new Traduccion();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TraductorApp window = new TraductorApp();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TraductorApp() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblConsultas = new JLabel("Consultas");
        lblConsultas.setBounds(10, 11, 67, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblConsultas);

        JLabel lblPalabra = new JLabel("Palabra");
        lblPalabra.setBounds(10, 36, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPalabra);

        JLabel lblTraduccin = new JLabel("Traducci\u00F3n");
        lblTraduccin.setBounds(10, 61, 67, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblTraduccin);

        JLabel lblDicccionarios = new JLabel("Diccionarios");
        lblDicccionarios.setBounds(10, 105, 67, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDicccionarios);

        JLabel lblIngls = new JLabel("Ingl\u00E9s");
        lblIngls.setBounds(10, 130, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblIngls);

        JLabel lblAdiciones = new JLabel("Adiciones");
        lblAdiciones.setBounds(10, 155, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblAdiciones);

        JLabel lblEnEspaol = new JLabel("En espa\u00F1ol");
        lblEnEspaol.setBounds(10, 180, 67, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnEspaol);

        JLabel lblEnIngls = new JLabel("En ingl\u00E9s");
        lblEnIngls.setBounds(10, 212, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnIngls);

        JLabel lblEnFrancs = new JLabel("En franc\u00E9s");
        lblEnFrancs.setBounds(10, 237, 67, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblEnFrancs);

        textPalabra = new JTextField();
        textPalabra.setBounds(109, 33, 117, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPalabra);
        textPalabra.setColumns(10);

        textTraduccion = new JTextField();
        textTraduccion.setBounds(109, 58, 117, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textTraduccion);
        textTraduccion.setColumns(10);

        NumPalIng = new JTextField();
        NumPalIng.setEditable(false);
        NumPalIng.setBounds(109, 127, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(NumPalIng);
        NumPalIng.setColumns(10);

        NumPalFran = new JTextField();
        NumPalFran.setEditable(false);
        NumPalFran.setBounds(316, 127, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(NumPalFran);
        NumPalFran.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblFrancs = new JLabel("Franc\u00E9s");
        lblFrancs.setBounds(260, 130, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblFrancs);

        AgregarEsp = new JTextField();
        AgregarEsp.setBounds(109, 177, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(AgregarEsp);
        AgregarEsp.setColumns(10);

        AgregarIng = new JTextField();
        AgregarIng.setBounds(109, 206, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(AgregarIng);
        AgregarIng.setColumns(10);

        AgregarFran = new JTextField();
        AgregarFran.setBounds(109, 234, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(AgregarFran);
        AgregarFran.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnEnIngls = new JButton("En ingl\u00E9s");
        btnEnIngls.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   int dick =1;
                   String a = textPalabra.getText();
                   String traduccion =  arr1.busquedapalabra(a,dick);

                    textTraduccion.setText(traduccion);
            }
        });
        btnEnIngls.setBounds(236, 57, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnIngls);

        JButton btnEnFrancs = new JButton("En franc\u00E9s");
        btnEnFrancs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int i =0;
              Traduccion t1 = new Traduccion(AgregarEsp.getText(),null,AgregarFran.getText());
              t1.guardarinfo(t1, i);
              AgregarEsp.setText("");
              AgregarFran.setText("");
            }
        });
        btnEnFrancs.setBounds(335, 57, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnEnFrancs);

        JButton btnAdicionarIng = new JButton("Adicionar");
        btnAdicionarIng.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                   int i =1;
                    Traduccion t1 = new Traduccion(AgregarEsp.getText(),AgregarIng.getText(),null);
                    t1.guardarinfo(t1, i);

                    AgregarEsp.setText("");
                    AgregarIng.setText("");

                Traduccion trad1 = new Traduccion(AgregarEsp.getText(),AgregarIng.getText(),AgregarFran.getText());

            }
        });
        btnAdicionarIng.setBounds(236, 208, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdicionarIng);

        JButton btnAdicionarFran = new JButton("Adicionar");
        btnAdicionarFran.setBounds(236, 233, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdicionarFran);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Es importante que indiques el mensaje de error el cual tambièn te puede indicar la lìnea que tiene el problema.

Answer (score 1):

No das suficiente información para determinar tu problema, de hecho, no hay mucha lógica en preguntar *cómo llamar a este método*. Simplemente crea el objeto y llama al método; no hay mayor misterio.

Sin embargo me parece un ejercicio divertido e interesante para ir aprendiendo el lenguaje. Yo he imaginado otra alternativa, por ejemplo, usando diccionarios y servicios, incluso el [anti]patrón Singleton y métodos `default` de Java 8.

#### Traductores

Los traductores son solo dos clases vacías que implementan `Translater`. Esta interface recibe el texto a traducir y el diccionario en el cual tiene que buscar. Esta interface tiene un método `default` que está disponible desde Java 8; de esta manera no repetimos código en las implementaciones.

```
public interface Translater {

    public default String translate(String text, Dictionary dic) {
        String[] words = text.split(" ");
        String translation = "";

        for(String word : words) {
            String translateWord = dic.searchWord(word);
            translation += translateWord + " ";
        }
        return translation;
    }
}
```

Y sus implementaciones (vacías porque no tienen que hacer nada):

```
public class EnglishTranslater implements Translater {


}

public class FrenchTranslater implements Translater {


}
```

#### Diccionarios

Los diccionarios especializados (hijos) deben ser singletons, porque solo interesa que exista un solo diccionario de cada lenguaje.

```
public abstract class Dictionary {

    protected final static Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

    public final void addEntry(String word, String translate) {
        dictionary.put(word, translate);
    }

    public final String searchWord(String word) {
        String translate = "Sin resultados";
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dictionary.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getKey().equals(word)) {
                translate = entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return translate;
    }
}
```

Y sus implementaciones. Aquí las implementaciones sí deben contenedor código, porque agregamos palabras al diccionario cuando el ClassLoader carga las clases y porque las hacemos Singleton.

```
public class SpanishEnglishDictionary extends Dictionary {

    private final static SpanishEnglishDictionary INSTANCE
                         = new SpanishEnglishDictionary();

    static {
        dictionary.put("casa", "house");
        dictionary.put("perro", "dog");
        dictionary.put("gato", "cat");
        dictionary.put("corriendo", "running");
        dictionary.put("alrededor", "around");
        dictionary.put("el", "the");
        dictionary.put("está", "is");
        dictionary.put("la", "the");
        dictionary.put("de", "of");
    }

    private SpanishEnglishDictionary() {

    }

    public static SpanishEnglishDictionary getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}

public final class SpanishFrenchDictionary extends Dictionary {

    private final SpanishFrenchDictionary INSTANCE = 
                                        new SpanishFrenchDictionary();

    private SpanishFrenchDictionary() {

    }

    public static SpanishFrenchDictionary getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

#### Servicio de traducción

El servicio de traducción es la capa de servicio. A esta clase le encargarás traducir el texto y el se encargará de mandarlo a traducir internamente.

```
public class TranslateService {

    public String translate(String text, Language lang) {
        Translater translater = null;
        Dictionary dictionary = null;

        if(lang == Language.ENGLISH) {
            translater = new SpanishEnglishTranslater();
            dictionary = SpanishEnglishDictionary.getInstance();
        }
        if(lang == Language.FRENCH) {
            translater = new SpanishFrenchTranslater();
            dictionary = SpanishFrenchDictionary.getInstance();
        }
        return translater.translate(text, dictionary);
    }
}
```

#### Interfaz gráfica de usuario

Un ejemplo sencillo de interfaz gráfica de usuario. Tiene un textarea en donde se escribe el texto y un combo en donde se elije el idioma al cual traducir. El resultado se muestra en la otra textarea de salida.

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea txtInput;
    private JTextArea txtOutput;
    private JComboBox<String> cboTargetLang;
    private JButton actionBtn;

    public MainWindow() {
        super("TinyTraductor");
        setLayout(null);

        txtInput = new JTextArea();
        txtOutput = new JTextArea();
        cboTargetLang = new JComboBox<>();
        actionBtn = new JButton();

        cboTargetLang.addItem("Inglés");
        cboTargetLang.addItem("Francés");
        cboTargetLang.setBounds(10, 15, 95, 25);

        actionBtn.setText("Traducir");
        actionBtn.setBounds(165, 15, 95, 25);
        actionBtn.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            translate();
        });

        txtInput.setBounds(10, 50, 250, 60);
        txtInput.setLineWrap(true);

        txtOutput.setBounds(10, 120, 250, 60);
        txtOutput.setLineWrap(true);
        txtOutput.setEditable(false);

        this.add(cboTargetLang);
        this.add(actionBtn);
        this.add(txtInput);
        this.add(txtOutput);

        this.setSize(270, 220);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void translate() {
        TranslateService service = new TranslateService();
        String inputText = txtInput.getText();
        String translation = "";
        String lang = cboTargetLang.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(lang.equals("Inglés")) {
            translation = service.translate(inputText, Language.ENGLISH);
        }
        if(lang.equals("Francés")) {
            translation = service.translate(inputText, Language.FRENCH);
        }
        txtOutput.setText(translation);
    }
}
```

Si te fijas en el método translate obtenemos del combo qué lenguaje se ha escogido para traducir y obtenemos la traducción por medio del servicio. `Language` es solo un enum con 2 valores: `INGLÉS` y `FRANCÉS`.

#### Resultado

[image: Screenshot]

Obviamente este pequeño ejemplo escapa a muchos detalles, como palabras con varios signficados, quizás en lugar de `Map<String, String>` debería ser `Map<String, List<String>>`, también conjugaciones, etc., que son detalles mucho más complejos.

Comment: Diría que no deberías forzar el uso del patrón singleton en este caso. Para que el diseño sea más flexible en lugar de crear tu propio singleton sería mejor definir un `public enum Dictionaries extends Dictionary` y cada entrada (que ya es un singleton en tiempo de compilación y asegurado por la JVM por ClassLoader) es un traductor por sí solo. De esa manera puedes eliminar la palabra `static` del `Map` definido en `Dictionary` y mover el método `translate` al `enum` en lugar de tenerlo en `TranslateService`.

Comment: Asimismo, te permite tener menos clases y realizar el trabajo favoreciendo composición sobre herencia.